# Making phone calls programmatically

Tags: iphone

How can we make phone calls programmatically without using the code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://9423456789"]];
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use that approach?

Comment: That's like saying *'how do I make a string without using NSString?* Why don't you want to use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://9423456789"]];` ?

Comment: you want to call programmatically but with out Code !!!

Comment: @Vladmir But my app is switching to the Phone app and it's cannot turn back to my app after ending the call. I need the call to be made within my app

Answer (score 4):

The method you've suggested *is* the only means of programmatically requesting that a call is placed.

If you're attempting to subvert the user's acceptance of the call, then this isn't possible using the public APIs.

Comment: I need to create an app like the 'Phone' app in iPhone

Comment: @Prasanth This isn't possible and even if it was Apple wouldn't accept it into the store, if that's relevant.

Comment: But the my app is switching to the Phone app and it's cannot turn back to my app after ending the call. I need the call to be made within my app

Answer (score 1):

So do this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://9423456789"]];
```

Then create a local notification that pops up in 1 seconds to bring the user back to your app.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make a call completely within your own application is to create your own VoIP-like solution. You can't make cellular phone calls within your own app.

It's completely user-controllable and, just like sending SMS and email, should stay that way. There were too many applications for Windows Mobile for example, which would send premium SMS behind user's back.

Answer (score 0):

@Prasanth T R

> But the my app is switching to the Phone app and it's cannot turn back
>   to my app after ending the call. I need the call to be made within my
>   app

To go back to your app, use telprompt://9423456789 instead of tel://9423456789

using "telprompt://" when a call finish the user will go back to your app

```
NSString *phoneDigits = @"9423456789";
NSString *phoneNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat@"telprompt://%@",phoneDigits];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]]
```